# Curl as variable, assign output to variable

Tags: bash, curl

I have problem with assigning curl as variable and assign curl's output to variable:

```
#get results url, format json
URL=$(curl https://api.apifier.com/xy)
#jq is a cli json interpreter
#resultUrl contains the final URL which we want download
OK= "$URL" | jq '.resultsUrl'
#api probably is running
sleep 5
curl "$OK"
```

Maybe it is trivial, but I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Change `OK= "$URL" | jq '.resultsUrl'` to `OK=$(echo $URL | jq '.resultsUrl')`. You should probably check that OK isn't null before you attempt to curl it.

Comment: How can you know the correct syntax to set `URL`, but not use that same syntax to set `OK`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is:

```
jq '.resultsUrl'
```

outputs the field `resultsUrl` *with quotes*, so curl does not process it correctly. Furthermore, `$URL | ...` does not work, you would have to use `echo` or `curl` directly.

Try

```
OK=$(curl -s https://api.apifier.com/v1/xHbBnrZ9rxF4CdKjo/crawlers/Example_Alcatraz_Cruises/execute?token=nJ9ohCHZPaJRFEb7nFqtzm76u | jq -r '.resultsUrl')
curl -s "$OK"
```

which results for me in

```
[{   "id": 2,   "url": "https://www.alcatrazcruises.com/SearchEventDaySpan.aspx?date=02-25-2016&selected=", "loadedUrl": "https://www.alcatrazcruises.com/SearchEventDaySpan.aspx?date=02-25-2016&selected=", "requestedAt": "2016-02-25T23:24:52.611Z",   "loadingStartedAt": "2016-02-25T23:24:54.663Z",   "loadingFinishedAt": "2016-02-25T23:24:55.642Z",   "loadErrorCode": null,   "pageFunctionStartedAt": "2016-02-25T23:24:55.839Z",   "pageFunctionFinishedAt": "2016-02-25T23:24:55.841Z",   "uniqueKey": "https://www.alcatrazcruises.com/SearchEventDaySpan.aspx?date=02-25-2016&selected=", "type": "UserEnqueued", ...
```

This should be what you expect.

However, sometimes the first API call yields an error:

```
{
  "type": "ALREADY_RUNNING",
  "message": "The act is already running and concurrent execution is not allowed"
}
```

so resultsURL will be `null`, you will have to handle this error case.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to mention that resultUrl contains quotes. It is still not workin, the current result is: []. If it helps I can post here a sample link.

Comment: Yes, do that please  ;)

Comment: https://api.myjson.com/bins/4g7q7 - hmm with this json it's working. I think maybe that's the problem, that $OK variable contains URL with parameters?

Comment: @Adrian showed you my input and output, what is different on your side?

Comment: I do not see any parameters in the resultUrl: `https://api.apifier.com/v1/execs/yxcxycxycycx/results`

Comment: I created a new test account so I can share here an actual url: https://api.apifier.com/v1/xHbBnrZ9rxF4CdKjo/crawlers/Example_Alcatraz_Cruises/execute?token=nJ9ohCHZPaJRFEb7nFqtzm76u - can you please test with this? If you get "already running" results, please wait a few seconds.

Comment: @Adrian I tested and extended the answer with the results

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
OK= "$URL" | jq '.resultsURL'
```

sets the environment variable `OK` to an empty string, then tries to execute `"$URL"` as a command and pipe its output to `jq`. If you want to set`OK` to the result of a command, you have to use `$OK=(...)`, just like you did when setting `URL`. The correct syntax is:

```
OK=$(echo "$URL" | jq '.resultsURL')
```

And to remove the quotes from the output of `.jq`, you can do:

```
OK=$(echo "$URL" | jq '.resultsURL' | tr -d '"')
```

Comment: For whomever finds their way to this cranny of the internet, in Jun 2020, the `jq -r` option removes quotes from strings, obviating the need for `tr -d '"'`.